# JQuery event of input array

Tags: jquery, arrays, events, triggers

I don't know how to trigger an input if this is a array.

I can read the value, but i don't know what is the input that have made the event.

```
$('input[name^="months"]').change(function() {
alert($(this).val());
});

<input type="text" name="months[january]" value="100">
<input type="text" name="months[february]" value="150">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the change() function includes `event`

```
$('input[name^="months"]').change(function(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: And do you know a easy method for get the month (january) instead of parse all the text, because my output is like this.
<input alt="months[january]" type="checkbox" id="months[january]" name="months[january]" value="1" checked="">

Comment: do you mean get the value out of that textbox? is `$(this).val()` not working?